# Query - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't have knowledge of Rails

Please, how do I make this query in Rails?

```
SELECT *, count(v.id) numero_votos FROM ideas i left join votes v on v.idea_id = i.id group by i.id order by numero_votos desc, i.created_at
```

I tried this...

```
@listOfIdeas = Idea.find(:all, joins: "LEFT JOIN 'votes' on votes.idea_id = ideas.id",
                                    select: "ideas.*, count(votes.id) numero_de_votos",
                                    group: "ideas.id",
                                    order: "numero_de_votos DESC, ideas.created_at DESC")
```

But, didn't work, it's showing me this message:

> Couldn't find all Ideas with 'id': (all, {:joins=>"LEFT JOIN 'votes' on votes.idea_id = ideas.id", :select=>"ideas.*, count(votes.id) numero_de_votos", :group=>"ideas.id", :order=>"numero_de_votos DESC, ideas.created_at DESC"}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)

Rails version: 5.1.4

Thanks!

Comment: `correct the sql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query looks strange. If your sql query is:

```
SELECT i.*, count(v.id) AS numero_votos 
FROM ideas i 
LEFT JOIN votes v ON v.idea_id = i.id 
GROUP BY i.id 
ORDER BY numero_votos DESC, i.created_at
```

Then, you should try something as:

```
Idea.select("ideas.*, count(votes.id) AS numero_votos ")
    .joins("LEFT JOIN votes ON votes.idea_id = ideas.id")
    .group("ideas.id")
    .order("numero_votos DESC")
    .order("ideas.created_at")
```

Comment: Thanks your help! But, I need to make a Left Join, 
because I need to show all the ideas, and when I change to "left_joins" appears to me the message "undefined method"

Comment: sorry I give to you an inner join. I'm updating my response now.

Comment: doc on active record join here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins